# Connect to mysql server by c# code

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, connection

I am trying using c# code to connect to mysql server that installed on vmware machine and execute query and I can`t do that.
I tested the connection with uld file on my host and that worked.
I also tested the code on a sql server that I am not hosting on my pc and that was worked for me.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        connString = "SERVER=(Main Server Ip)\\SSER;PORT=3306;DATABASE=......;UID=.......;PASSWORD=......";
        try
        {
            conn = new MySqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = connString;
            conn.Open();
            //    MessageBox.Show("connection success");


            string query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Table_1";
            //Create Command
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
            //Create a data reader and Execute the command
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


            //Read the data and store them in the list
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dataReader["id"] + "");
                Console.WriteLine(dataReader["num"] + "");
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is that \\SER? Just use the IP and _dbo.Table_1_ ? dbo is Sql Server.

Comment: As a general advice, your data access logic should not lie on the UI's click event handler

Comment: What did not work? Which error/exception occours?

Comment: @Steve \\SSER = \SSER (SSER it`s the mysql server hostname) , dbo.Table_1 is the table name
@BrunoSaboia I can`t understand if you talk about the connection info , I don`t posted the real details.
@H.G.Sandhagen Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts